# I'm to make a method that lists numbers 2-100 which lists factors of all numbers next to them

Tags: java

I'm to make a method that lists numbers 2-100 which lists factors of all numbers next to them; if there's no factor then list prime.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Factors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int limit = 100;
        for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            if( i % 2 != 0)
                System.out.println("Prime");
            else
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

This is all I have so far, my output is like this:

```
1 Prime
2 
3 Prime
4 
5 Prime
6 
7 Prime
8 
9 Prime
10 
11 Prime
12 
13 Prime
14 
15 Prime
16 
17 Prime
```

Clearly that's not right!

Comment: Is this all you've tried? Have you made any attempts to improve the code? Right now, this smells like you trying to get us to do your homework for you, and I'm allergic to that ...

Comment: I've tried some other things but simply enough, I don't think I was setting it up correctly. I can't get it to where it only says which is prime and factors the numbers which can be done so. Should I change my if statements?

Comment: Ok, so this isn't about factoring a particular arbitrary number, but about providing all factors for 2-100... Is it just prime factors or ALL factors (e.g. for 42 would you say 2,3,7 or 1,2,3,6,7,14,21,42)? If it's just the prime factors, then do you list each factor once, or do you have to take into account how many times it's involved? (e.g. for 8 do you say 2? or 2,2,2?)

Comment: Yes it's all factors and they're to be listed next to its number. We're on our loops unit and honestly I think it's one of the most confusing ones we've gone through yet!

Comment: Ok, then, the first part of the first answer provides a starting point ... for each number (2,3,4,5,6), loop through its multiples and add the base number to the list of factors for each multiple. So when you get to 7 for instance, you add 7 to the list for each of 14, 21, 28, 35 etc. Try implementing this and if you have specific problems with it, ask away.

Comment: I think I almost got it, just need to work on it a bit more but I'll figure it out at this point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To list all the multiples of the number use repetitive addition.

```
int num = 3;
int max = 100;

for(int i = num; i <= max; i += num)
 System.out.println(i);//3 6 9...
```

---

This is called [Sieve Of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), my Friend.

what your problem is that you only cosider the factors of 2, what about `3 5 7...`

You have to consider all those which were not marked as prime.

```
boolean[]primes = new boolean[max];
Arrays.fill(primes, true);

for(int i = 2; i * i < max; ++i)
 if(primes[i])//consider all those numbers which are marked prime till then
  for(int j = i * i; j < max; j += i)//get all factors of that number
   primes[j] = false;//mark all it's factors as not primes

for(int i = 2; i < max; ++i)
 if(primes[i])
  System.out.println(i + " Prime");
 else
  System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Probably because your initial answer - just the "Sieve" part - doesn't give any information about factoring. I'm not sure your enhancement is all that helpful either. You seem to be confusing the words "factor" and "multiple".